# How get single value from unique values php

Tags: php, zend-db

i getting values from query
I'm looking for output like this:

Please help me how can i do this i'm trying in function to get this

```
$cols = array ('test.title', 'test_stats.*' );
$select = $db->select () ->from ( 'test', $cols )
    ->join ( 'test_stats', 'test_stats.test_public_id = test.test_public_id', array ())
    ->where ( 'test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)' )
    ->order ( 'title' );
    $result = $db->fetchAll ( $select );
foreach ( $result as $row1 ) {
    $title = $row1 ['title'];
    $testPublicId = $row1 ['test_public_id'];
    $views = count($testPublicId);
}
    $select = $db->select ()
    ->from ( 'test_stats', array ('count(test_public_id) AS total_views' ))
    ->where ( 'test_public_id = ?', $publicId );
$result2 = $db->fetchAll ( $select );
foreach ( $result2 as $row2 ) {
$totalViews = $row2 ['total_views'];
$x= '<table>
<tr>
    <td > ' . $title . ' </td>
    <td > ' .$testPublicId . ' </td>
    <td > ' . $views . ' </td>
    <td > ' . $row1 ['addr'] . ' </td>
    <td > ' . $totalViews . ' </td>
</tr>
</table>';
}
}
print_r($x);
```

[image: i'm looking for out put like this]

Comment: If you add a distinct, wont that do the trick?

Comment: i have to retrieve all the ip addresses remaining all i have to distinguish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know zend_db but, here is sql query

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3,
GROUP_CONCAT(column_ip SEPARATOR ','),
column5
FROM table
GROUP BY column1,column2,column3,column5
```